# JavaScript parsing array getting individual characters rather than full words

Tags: javascript

So I have the following JavaScript that is causing me an issue when I try parse a variable

```
var fruit = [client.get_variable('fruitInv')];
var arrayLength = fruit.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
  print("Fruit is " + fruit[i]);    
}
```

when I process this I get 
a
p
p
l
e

o
r
a
n
g
e

etc..... so character by character rather than element by element what am I doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: What does `client.get_variable('fruitInv')` return?

Comment: What does `print` do?

Comment: if I do a print("Fruit inv " + fruit)   I get apple banana orange etc...

Comment: does client.get_variable('fruitInv') return an array or a string?

Comment: `console.log(typeof fruit)`, what does that give you?

Comment: says it is type of object